# The meaning of <P = any> in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I looked inside the `leaflet.js` definition file and there I found one strange thing: `Marker<P = any>`, where I can't figure out what `P = any` is for. I mean why is this not `P: any`?

*The class implementation:*

```
export class Marker<P = any> extends Layer {
    constructor(latlng: LatLngExpression, options?: MarkerOptions);
    toGeoJSON(): geojson.Feature<geojson.Point, P>;
    getLatLng(): LatLng;
    setLatLng(latlng: LatLngExpression): this;
    setZIndexOffset(offset: number): this;
    setIcon(icon: Icon | DivIcon): this;
    setOpacity(opacity: number): this;
    getElement(): HTMLElement | undefined;

    // Properties
    options: MarkerOptions;
    dragging?: Handler;
    feature?: geojson.Feature<geojson.Point, P>;
}
```

*The full definition file:*
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/leaflet/index.d.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Marker` is a generic type, with a type argument named `P`. Usually you have to specify the generic argument for a generic type. However if the definition of the generic type provides a default for the type argument (`P = any`) then the type can be used while omitting an explicit type argument:

```
let x: Marker // valid because there is a default of any for P will be the same as Marker<any>
let xy: Marker<number> // valid because Marker is generic
```

Comment: So let's say, if the `P` is type of `string`, then it should be `<P = string>`?

Comment: The definition provides the default of `any` you can't change the default, you can specify a type different to the default when you use the type ex `let foo:  Marker<string>`. If you were to change the definition to `Marker<P=string>` then yes the default would be string and `let x: Marker` would be the same as `let x: Marker<string>`